# Regex que permita un único espacio en blanco entre palabras C#

Tags: c#, regex

Sé que se ha preguntado varias cosas similares con el Regex, pero he indagado ya en bastantes preguntas y no logro solucionar aún mi problema, que es el siguiente.

En un input una persona puede ingresar sus apellidos, en caso de que sea un apellido compuesto se debe permitir que ingrese un solo espacio entre las palabras, así que por ejemplo "`De León`" estaría correcto, pero "`De  León`" no (Tiene doble espacio). Para eso estoy usando `Regex.IsMatch(inputApellido, patronRegex)`. En donde si da match, arroja el error.

En un principio intenté con el regex `[^a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]` (Ya que debe permitir solo letras y tildes), pero cuando se ingresa un apellido compuesto arroja error por el espacio. Luego intenté `[^a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]` (Añadiendo un espacio blanco al final), pero esto me permite cualquier cantidad de espacios entre palabras y no es el objetivo.

No estoy muy seguro de cómo proseguir ya que no sé cómo indicar que acepte uno y sólo un espacio entre las palabras del apellido (Digamos que espacios al principio o al final no importan porque puedo realizar un .Trim()). Agradecería mucho un poco de iluminación al respecto.

Comment: Ojala nadie se llame de agüero.... o algun apellido como d'acord... hacer estas cosas.. con los nombres... es dudoso.. Sobre tu regex no tengo idea...

Comment: Gracias igual por comentar. Los requerimientos son los que son. Pero estoy de acuerdo en que hay casos que no se han cubierto. Si fuera por mi, que el usuario ingrese el apellido que sea, pero ese es el problema de trabajar con requerimientos.

Comment: Entiendo lo de los requerimientos, pero una parte del trabajo de programador es aclarar estos problemas

Comment: Esto es c#, no java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static bool Match(string text){
    // el regex está formado por dos partes: 
    // 1. cadena de caracteres
    // 2. un espacio en blanco seguido de otra cadena de caracteres
    // siendo la segunda parte opcional
    string pattern = @"[^a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+(\s[^a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+)?";  

    Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);

    // Si hay un solo match significa que el apellido tiene solo un espacio
    // o no es un apellido compuesto
    return rg.Matches(text).Count == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este patrón debe funcionar `"\ {2,}"`

Con este patrón se buscan las coincidencias donde hay 2 o mas espacios en el texto ingresado, de tal forma que si el patrón se cumple, podrás ejecutar el procedimiento que hayas programado para ese caso.

La coma después del 2 indica que pueden ser mas de 2 espacios, si después de la coma se pone por ejemplo el 3, indicaría que debe encontrar mínimo 2 espacios y máximo 3.

Comment: 1) ¿Por qué el espacio está escapado? 2) con "{2,}" cubres cadenas de 2 espacios o más.

Comment: Si, es correcto, le falta la coma y el de doble espacio no vale, a menos que se valide en el evento changue.